# Multiple GET requests in Angular interfere the $scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m building a MEAN Application. I´ve got the problem that in one view, my $scope gets disabled, when I write a second `$http.get` to my controller.

**Here are the not working scopes**
[image: error]

**With this controller** (the //GET Media part disables the scopes and causes the error)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('projectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.myVar = false;
        $scope.toggle = function() {
            $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
        };
        $http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
            $scope.projects = res.data;
        });
        //GET Media
        $http.get('/uploads/media/'+projectId).then(function(data){
            console.log('Medien-Daten erhalten');
            $scope.media = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Best regards from Germany,

David

Comment: Why do you have `$scope` prepending your second GET request url? It's serving no purpose from what I can see.

Comment: This was a mistake, when I copy pasted the lines

Comment: Is `projectId` defined somewhere and accessible from the controller? Any errors in console?

Comment: have you hosted your code on some server?what error you are getting>

Comment: You got it man! I was just working on this part, and it was not final, but i couldn´t understand why the part above that wasn´t working. The Get Media request doesnt touch this part!?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Christopher Marshall, I forgot to define a variable for `projectId`. 
Now works this way:

```
$http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
                $scope.projects = res.data;
                var projectId = $scope.projects._id;
            });
            //GET Media
            $http.get('/uploads/media/'+projectId).then(function(data){
                console.log('Medien-Daten erhalten');
                $scope.media = data;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you're only getting your project id then, you should structure your app like this:

```
app.controller('projectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myVar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar
    };
    $http
        .get('/profile/project/')
        .then(function (res){
            $scope.projects = res.data;
            var projectId = $scope.projects._id;
            return $http.get('/uploads/media/'+projectId);
        })
        .then(function(data){
          console.log('Medien-Daten erhalten');
            $scope.media = data;        
        });
});
```

I've changed the promises so they happen one after another.